# Split a file containing rows of CSV into several files in shell or Sheets

Tags: shell, google-sheets, sh

Have a file (longlist.csv) containing 333 rows of 4 comma-separated values. Instead, I'll like it to be 4 files - 3 of 100 rows and 1 of the remainder (33).

What if you didn't know how many lines the file was and you wanted it to be split into separate files each comprised of 100 rows and one additional file for the remaining lines?

How can one do this using a shell command/script or Google Sheets?

*longlist.csv*

```
1A, 1B,1C, 1D
2A,2B, 2C, 2D
...
333A, 333B, 333C, 333D
```

Comment: ok. I created [longlist](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17fCepu-DdgxiriWrodXxNGA91GuEUzI7coEhPNZLaGQ/edit?usp=sharing) but with only 5 rows of 3 columns. In this example one could split this into 3 files of 2 rows instead of 4 files of up to 100 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can do it as follows with using `cat` and piping appropriate combinations of `head` and `tail` commands:

```
cat longlist.csv | head -n 100 > list_01.csv
cat longlist.csv | head -n 200 | tail -n 100 > list_02.csv
cat longlist.csv | tail -n 133 | head -n 100 > list_03.csv
cat longlist.csv | tail -n 33 > list_04.csv
```

I haven't tested on a file with 333 rows. I tested this concept on the smaller file and mapped it into data provided in your question.

**EDIT**

Generic solution to this problem is easier than I thought.

We can simply use `split` unix program as follows:

```
split -l 100 longlist.csv new
```

This command will generate files with names `newaa`, `newab`, `newac` and so on. Each file will contain 100 lines from the original file and the last file will contain remaining lines (in case we don't have round number of the initial lines). We can also omit `new` keyword in the end and then default prefix for the new files will be `x`.

Comment: Thank you for this. 
What if you didn't know how many lines the file was and you wanted it to be split into separate files each comprised of 100 rows and one additional file for the remaining lines?

Comment: @citizen I edited my answer. I found much easier and generic solution to this problem.